# PigUnit with Hadoop 2.x

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, classpath, apache-pig

I'm trying to use [PigUnit](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/test.html#Run+PigUnit) with Hadoop 2.4.1. I have a very simple Pig script that I want to execute inside a PigTest, but when I run this test I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.createJobContext(HadoopShims.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchPOStoreImpl.createStoreFunc(FetchPOStoreImpl.java:58)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POStore.setUp(POStore.java:103)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchLauncher.init(FetchLauncher.java:121)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchLauncher.launchPig(FetchLauncher.java:78)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:275)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1367)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1352)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1011)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:974)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:887)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:752)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:228)
    at org.apache.pig.pigunit.pig.PigServer.registerScript(PigServer.java:55)
    at org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest.registerScript(PigTest.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest.assertOutput(PigTest.java:242)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.PigTest.testSimplePigScript(PigTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

In Hadoop 2.4.1, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext is an interface, not a class, so it seems to me like PigUnit is somehow expecting an older version of Hadoop? If this is indeed the case, how do I point PigUnit to more recent Hadoop jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong verison of Pig. Pig has multiple artifacts on Maven, and I needed to provide a classifier in my `build.gradle` in order to specify the Pig jar that works against Hadoop 2.x:

```
compile "org.apache.pig:pig:${pigVersion}:h2"
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955104/how-to-specify-pig-0-13-0-h2-jar-dependency-in-build-gradle) helped me solve my Gradle/dependency issue.