# How to specify "pig-0.13.0-h2.jar" dependency in build.gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, classpath, apache-pig

To specify a Maven dependency in my project, I provide a *name*, a *group id*, and a *version*. This has been enough for every dependency in my project, save one. [Pig](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.pig|pig|0.13.0|jar) has multiple jars in the same artifact (not sure if I have the proper nomenclature; I'm still rather new to Maven), but I only need one.

Specifically, I need `pig-0.13.0-h2.jar`. However, when I provide the dependency

```
compile "org.apache.pig:pig:0.13.0"
```

in my `build.gradle`, only `pig-0.13.0.jar`, `pig-0.13.0-sources.jar`, and `pig-0.13.0.pom` are downloaded. I need the "*-h2.jar", because that's the correct one to work with my version of Hadoop.

Is there a way to tell Gradle (and, generally, Maven or whatever) that my compile dependency requires *this exact jar*, and that only this one should be included in the classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to specify the *[classifier](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#classifier)*. The following script will do the job:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile "org.apache.pig:pig:0.13.0:h2"
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'deps'
}
```